# nodejs: perform mapping function in batches to manage memory

Tags: node.js, memory-management, out-of-memory, async.js, tabula

### Context

I'm using Tabula to parse pdf tables.  I have a lot of pdfs and those pdfs have varying numbers of pages, anywhere from a couple to hundreds.  I'm trying to point my node.js program to an input folder and have it give me csvs of all the tables defined by regions I've determined.

Because of memory limitations, I can't just loop through the files, loop through the pages, and have tabula parse each table asynchronously.  So I looked around for how to do batches of tasks and `async.mapLimit` kept coming up.  It seems like it is supposed to do what I require, but for whatever reason, I'm only getting it to finish the first batch of size `limit` and then it "finishes" without going to the subsequent batches and performing the same task.

### Code

```js
const tabula = require('tabula-js');
require('pdfjs-dist');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const async = require('async');

// regions in every page that I care about
const region1 = "5.94,121.275,35.64,788.535";
const region2 = "38.61,159.885,85.14,788.535";
const region3 = "64.35,9.405,149.49,157.905";
const region4 = "87.12,159.885,146.52,789.525";
const region5 = "148.5,186.615,314.82,791.505";
const region6 = "151.47,7.425,313.83,181.665";
const region7 = "318.78,6.435,383.13,788.535";
const region8 = "386.1,10.395,479.16,216.315";
const region9 = "385.11,218.295,595.98,374.715";
const region10 = "386.1,377.685,481.14,791.505";
const region11 = "481.14,10.395,595.98,214.335";
const region12 = "483.12,376.695,596.97,778.635";

// handler for when tabula.js is done extracting table to csv
const handleTableParse = (err, data, title) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }

    if (!fs.existsSync('./output/')) {
        fs.mkdirSync('./output/');
    }

    if (fs.existsSync(`./output/${title}.csv`)) {
        fs.unlinkSync(`./output/${title}.csv`);
    }

    data.map(line => {
        fs.appendFileSync(`./output/${title}.csv`, `${line}\n`);
    });

}

// parse the tables found on each page in the pdf provided
const parseTablesInPDF = (pdf, numPages) => {

    const pageNumbers = Array.from(new Array(numPages), (x, i) => i + 1);

    const ext = path.extname(pdf);
    const filename = path.basename(pdf, ext)
        .split(' ')
        .join('_');

    // let it do 5 pages at a time for memory management reasons
    async.mapLimit(pageNumbers, 5, pageNumber => {
        const region1Data = tabula(pdf, { pages: `${pageNumber}`, area: region1 });
        region1Data.extractCsv((err, data) => handleTableParse(err, data, `${filename}_region1_page${pageNumber}`));

        const region2Data = tabula(pdf, { pages: `${pageNumber}`, area: region2 });
        region2Data.extractCsv((err, data) => handleTableParse(err, data, `${filename}_region2_page${pageNumber}`));

        const region3Data = tabula(pdf, { pages: `${pageNumber}`, area: region3 });
        region3Data.extractCsv((err, data) => handleTableParse(err, data, `${filename}_region3_page${pageNumber}`));

        const regino4Data = tabula(pdf, { pages: `${pageNumber}`, area: region4 });
        region4Data.extractCsv((err, data) => handleTableParse(err, data, `${filename}_region4_page${pageNumber}`));

        const region5Data = tabula(pdf, { pages: `${pageNumber}`, area: region5 });
        region5Data.extractCsv((err, data) => handleTableParse(err, data, `${filename}_region5_page${pageNumber}`));

        const region6Data = tabula(pdf, { pages: `${pageNumber}`, area: region6 });
        region6Data.extractCsv((err, data) => handleTableParse(err, data, `${filename}_region6_page${pageNumber}`));

        const region7Data = tabula(pdf, { pages: `${pageNumber}`, area: region7 });
        region7Data.extractCsv((err, data) => handleTableParse(err, data, `${filename}_region7_page${pageNumber}`));

        const region8Data = tabula(pdf, { pages: `${pageNumber}`, area: region8 });
        region8Data.extractCsv((err, data) => handleTableParse(err, data, `${filename}_region8_page${pageNumber}`));

        const region9Data = tabula(pdf, { pages: `${pageNumber}`, area: region9 });
        region9Data.extractCsv((err, data) => handleTableParse(err, data, `${filename}_region9_page${pageNumber}`));

        const region10Data = tabula(pdf, { pages: `${pageNumber}`, area: region10 });
        region10Data.extractCsv((err, data) => handleTableParse(err, data, `${filename}_region10_page${pageNumber}`));

        const regino11Data = tabula(pdf, { pages: `${pageNumber}`, area: region11 });
        region11Data.extractCsv((err, data) => handleTableParse(err, data, `${filename}_region11_page${pageNumber}`));

        const region12Data = tabula(pdf, { pages: `${pageNumber}`, area: region12 });
        region12Data.extractCsv((err, data) => handleTableParse(err, data, `${filename}_region12_page${pageNumber}`));
    })
}

// start the process of parsing pdfs, 5 at a time
async.mapLimit(fs.readdirSync('./input/2016'), 5, file => {
    const data = new Uint8Array(fs.readFileSync(`./input/2016/${file}`));
    PDFJS.getDocument(data).then(document => {
        parseTablesInPDF(`./input/2016/${file}`, document.numPages);
    })
}, () => console.log('DONE!'));
```

### Problem

At the end of the run, I only get 5 pages of each pdf when I know that several have over 100 pages in them.  It seems that every pdf file is being processed, but for whatever reason, I only get 5 pages for each.

This is my first time using some of these libraries.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks in advance!

### My Thoughts

Could it be that I'm doing a `async.mapLimit` inside of a `async.mapLimit`?  A `console.log(pageNumber)` inside of `parseTablesInPDF`'s `async.mapLimit` call does reveal that I'm only getting 1 through 5...

Am I failing silently?  How do I know?

### Update

I've realized that what I'm asking the node application to do is all running in a single process.  I have been trying to come up with a working example I can update this question to that involves forking `child_process`es but I'm not sure how to control how many concurrent `child_process`es are running at once.  It seems that the `send({...})` method is asynchronous and I'm not sure how to "await" it.

How does one control the concurrency of forked child processes in node?

Comment: You might not be getting the full benefit of processing things in parallel, since node is single-threaded and the tasks you're doing seem to be CPU bound. Otoh, have you done the simple thing of just having a for loop and processing thing serially? You shouldn't run out of memory as data for previous PDFs would be garbage collected.

Comment: What ended up happening when I tried just looping through everything serially is that my whole virtual machine's operating system froze and I had to restart the machine each time I tried this.  At that point I was guessing that the single-threaded nature of my node application was not playing nicely with the rest of the running processes and I had a big memory problem.  But I'll try again...Maybe I didn't do it quite the way you suggested.

Comment: That's sounds like a strange behaviour. If you've allowed your VM to have more than 1 processors, node should consume one of them at 100%, but the rest should be free to allow you to cancel the program etc through the command line or what have you. But even if it were single-processor, you'd still not see such a drastic failure, because the other programs would get some sort of CPU time-slice. Perhaps there's something strange going on in the PDFjs functions you're calling? Perhaps try using _delete_ in a strictly serial program to explicitly indicate which data is no longer of use?

Comment: Interesting, I'll take that into account today while I try to figure this out.  I've tried this process on just one pdf with 106 pages in it instead of a folder of pdfs and it froze up the UI of my vm for about 10 seconds and then finished its job.  So I started googling non-blocking node techniques.  

What do you mean use delete to explicitly indicate which data is no longer in use?  Can you explain what you mean?